# How to share a contact from iOS app to Whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller, vcf-vcard, cncontact

Sharing .vcf to WhatsApp using UIActivityViewController fails by showing plugin net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension invalidated error

**Sharing image or text is working using UIActivityViewController, But sharing .vcf is not working with whatsapp (working fine for mail/message/messenger etc).**

```
NSData *pVcfData     = [CNContactVCardSerialization dataWithContacts:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pContact] error:&pError]; // creating contact data from CNContactVCardSerialization

NSURL *pFileURL      = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:pFileNameWithAllowedCharacters]]; //  wrote the data to file

NSError *pWriteError = nil;

if ([pVcfData writeToURL:pFileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&pWriteError])
{
   NSArray *pActivityItems  =  @[pFileURL]; //  passed the file URL as ActivityItem for UIActivityViewController

   UIActivityViewController *pActivityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:pActivityItems applicationActivities:nil];

   [pActivityVC setValue:pContactName forKey:@"subject"];

   [self presentViewController:pActivityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Is there any other method to share contact to whatsapp other than .vcf. Please share any suggestion.**